# A strange criterion for compactness

Tags: metric-spaces

Is it true that if every continuous real-valued function on a metric space is bounded, then that metric space is compact

Comment: Already asked
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449358/true-or-not-compact-iff-every-continuous-function-is-bounded

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181367/pseudocompactness-does-not-imply-compactness

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/114338/12042) gives a complete explanation.

Comment: @Robert: No, that is a distinctly different question. This one is specifically about **metric** spaces.

Comment: Ah sorry, haven't seen the "metric", in which case it's trivially true. My bad !

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ is not compact, then take a injective sequence $(x_n)_n$ of elements of $X$ such that the values set $X_f := \{ x_n\;|\;n\in\mathbf{N}\}$ is discrete and closed. Then look at the function $f : X_f \to\mathbf{R}$ defined by sending $x_n$ to $n$. This is continuous and not bounded. Now [Uryshon's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) ensures that $f$ can be extended to a continuous function (still noted) $f:X\to\mathbb R$ which won't be bounded.